# Linux simulate write() system call failure using ptrace()

Tags: linux, system-calls, ptrace

I am trying to simulate failure of write() system call.
I have read that return value -1 (in EAX) indicates error in system call and errno gives the exact reason for failure.
I am trying to intercept system call write() return -1 in EAX register and set the "errno" to some error value.
puts() internally uses write(), which is system call number 4.
If i do perror("Error:") in the child, it should show the error corresponding to "errno" which i would like to set.

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>   /* For constants ORIG_EAX etc */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main()
{   pid_t child;
    int status;
    long orig_eax,eax,params[3];
    int ret_val=-1,insyscall=0;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    child = fork();
    if(child == 0) {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);

        execl("/home/kashi/Documents/2nd_Sem/MyPrgms/ptrace/ramana/write", "write", NULL);
    //execl("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
    }
    else {
      while(1)
      {
        wait(&status);
          if(WIFEXITED(status))
              break;

          orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                     child, 4 * ORIG_EAX, NULL);

      if(orig_eax == 4) 
          {
        ptrace( PTRACE_GETREGS, child, 0, &regs );
        printf("Write called with %ld, %ld %ld\n",regs.ebx, regs.ecx,regs.edx);

             if(insyscall == 0) 
             {
                /* Syscall entry */
                printf("In %d\n",insyscall);
                insyscall = 1;
             }
             else
             {
                /* Syscall exit */
        regs.orig_eax=-1;
        **errno=11;     //This errno should be set in the child process, how to do it?**

        ptrace( PTRACE_SETREGS, child, 0, &regs );
        eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, child, 4 * ORIG_EAX, NULL);
                printf("Write returned with %ld\n", eax);
        insyscall = 0;
             }
          }   

        //printf("The child made a "
        //       "system call %ld\n", regs.orig_eax);
       ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, child, NULL, NULL);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The tracee program (testwrite.c) is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/ptrace.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<errno.h>

//int display(char *p);
int main()
{

    printf("Hi Kashi\n");
    perror("Error: ");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
[kashi@localhost ramana]$ ./test.sh
In 0
Hi Kashi
Write returned with -1
In 0
**Error: : Success**
Write returned with -1
```

The perror("Error:") displays text message corresponding to "errno". I am not able to set this "errno" in child process, how can i do it?

Comment: It is usually simpler to make `write` fail with disk quotas or limits (`ulimit` in bash) ...

Comment: I want to develop a framework where i can simulate any system call failure, write() is just one of the example.

Comment: I think the system call returns the negative of the errno in eax, and the C library interface looks at this and decides whether to set errno and return -1.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I came across this link: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-return-values.html